# HTMLAgilityPack not recognising first element

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I am trying to get the games schedule from site (https://www.espn.com/nba/schedule ).

The tables, in simplified terms, have the following structure:

```
<div class="ScheduleTables">
<div> Date </div>
<table class="Table"> ... </table>
</div>
```

The first table is not fetched - it is ignored. Instead, the table from the day following the latest one displayed on the page is fetched (this table is not displayed on the linked page, and I do not see it in the HTML code of the page). The element also contains a nested element displaying the date. The date always appears from the previous table instead of the correct one.

```
var web = new HtmlWeb();
var document = web.Load(StatsUrl);
var schedules = document.QuerySelectorAll("div").Where(d => d.HasClass("ScheduleTables"));
var tbodys = schedules.QuerySelectorAll("tbody");
```

This is my code that does not return correct elements.
I've also tried `document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[contains(@class, 'ScheduleTables')]")` but the results were the same.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You might want to run the offending HTML through a compliance checker. I don't have the specifics in front of me, but we have a tool, which also uses html-agility-pack (to harvest and then query some status pages that our embedded devices generate). Those pages sometimes have errors in them, e.g. missing <body> tags, that browsers can handle but agility pack cannot. What I do is, if I detect that some crucial tags are missing, I "massage" the html by adding the missing pieces before passing it onto agility pack.

Comment: Could you please specify the compliance checker or technology that works alongside HTMLAgilityPack and is mentioned in your message?. I've tried HTML Sanitizer but it doesn't work with HTMLAgilityPack

Comment: I never attempted to combine the two directly - IIRC, I just plugged the failing HTML into WWW's checker and then by trial and error found out, which HTML errors present in the documents caused agility pack to fail. My input HTML is considerably simpler in structure than what you have here, though.